Solving and plotting roots of a non polynomial equation with parameters
In Mathematica 12, I want to find the roots r of this equation in terms of the parameters M and Q, then plot r versus Q for some values of M.
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = -8 Q^4 + r^3 (2 M - Log[r]) + 
   r (2 (4 + 9 M) Q^2 - 9 Q^2 Log[r]) + 
   r^2 (-2 - 8 M - 12 M^2 + 4 Log[r] + 12 M Log[r] - 3 Log[r]^2);

For this purpose, I made a function I called Rsol[q], which worked, with the following error message
Rsol[q_] := NSolve[eqn == 0 && r > 0, r, Reals] /. {M -> 2, Q -> q}    
Rsol[3]
    NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.
    {{r -> 2.98705}, {r -> 53.6628}}

The problem is, when I tried to plot it using plot, I got an empty frame with error messages
Plot[Rsol[q], {q, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]

I would be very thankful if someone help me.

ContourPlot3D[eqn == 0, {M, -10, 10}, {Q, -10, 10}, {r, .1, 10}]

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = -8  Q^4 + r^3  (2  M - Log[r]) + 
   r  (2  (4 + 9  M)  Q^2 - 9  Q^2  Log[r]) + 
   r^2  (-2 - 8  M - 12  M^2 + 4  Log[r] + 12  M  Log[r] - 
      3  Log[r]^2);

Manipulate[
 M = m;
 ContourPlot[
  eqn == 0, {Q, -10, 10}, {r, 0.1, 10},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Q, r})],
 {{m, 1.5, "M"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {m}]



Thank you so much @Bob HAnlon. It was really neat. I understood that it is not neccessary to find the solution for and eqn, if we eventually want to plot it. We can simply ContourPlot eqn==0. Am I right?
Anothe question: why did you use the last options SynchronousUpdating -> False and  TrackedSymbols :> {m}. When I deleted them, it worked too! Thus, I didn't understand theire role!

Those options provide more stable operation of the Manipulate.
